# How to write faster update

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

How to make the Oracle SQL Update faster, table contains around 5 million records.

```
update TableName set    
ColumnName1= TRANSLATE (Columnname1,
   '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
   '9876543210zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbaZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA'),
ColumnName2=  '';
```

It's taking **20mins** to update.

What can I do to speed up the query?

Answer (score 1):

You can split into translate part and update part.

translate part (without locking database):

```
select     
 TRANSLATE (
     Columnname1,
     '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
     '9876543210zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbaZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA') AS ColumnName1
, ' ' AS ColumnName2
from TableName;
```

update part:
you can use sql-loader, e.g. like [this](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:70109473088345).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, an empty string is equivalent to NULL in Oracle.

You're doing this the most efficient way possible.; you're updating the entire table in a single UPDATE; so you've got few choices here. The most obvious thing to do is to parallelize.

If you're using Oracle Enterprise Edition you can use the [PARALLEL hint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements006.htm#sthref671):

```
update /*+ parallel(tablename, 4) */ tablename
   set col1 = <some stuff>
     , col2 = null
```

4 here is the number of parallel sessions.

If you're using the Standard Edition then it's worth looking at [DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_parallel_ex.htm#CHDIJACH); this chunks the table you're updating first and then executes the UPDATE in parallel:

```
declare
  l_sql varchar2(32767);
  l_status number;
begin


  dbms_parallel_execute.create_task ('mytask');

  dbms_parallel_execute.create_chunks_by_rowid
       ('mytask', user, 'TABLENAME', true, 10000);

  l_sql := 'update /*+ rowid (dda) */ tablename 
               set col1 = <some stuff>
                 , col2 = null
             where rowid between :start_id and :end_id';

  dbms_parallel_execute.run_task
      ( 'mytask', l_sql, dbms_sql.native, parallel_level => 4);

  l_status := dbms_parallel_execute.task_status('mytask');

  if l_status = dbms_parallel_execute.finished then
     dbms_parallel_execute.drop_task('mytask');
  end if;

end;
/
```

The other option is to upgrade the infrastructure of course...

Answer (score -1):

This might work faster.

```
update TableName set
ColumnName1 = replace(replace(replace(@Columnname1 COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS,'0123456789', '9876543210')COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba')COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA') 
ColumnName2 = '' ;
```

Let me know if its any better than your previous query.

Comment: This wont work, translate works on character level where replace work on word level. in translate 0 is replaced with 9 and 1 with 8 and so on. But in replace 0123456789 will be replaced with 9876543210. it wont be same.

Comment: This works @Mani. 


`declare @Columnname1 nvarchar(62)


set @columnname1 = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'


select replace(replace(replace(@Columnname1 COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS,'0123456789', '9876543210')COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba')COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA') `



I tried this and works perfect.
Should try implementing this on a table to see its performance.

Comment: You still didnt get the point.  Lets consider one of my column as 0123456789 and other as 12377. replace will change only the first value but translate will change the second value (12377 to 87622) as well.